# Arrange elements in columns vertically shifted relative to one another

Tags: css, css-grid

I am looking for a way to achieve this effect:

On the mobile layout, elements are placed one under the other in a column:

[image]

On the desktop layout, however, elements are placed in two columns, with odd elements in one column and even elements in the other. The columns are shifted vertically relative to one another:

[image]

I wonder whether there is a CSS-only way to achieve this positioning. CSS grid comes tantalizingly close, if only there were a way to say that, for example, `nth-child(n+1)` would span rows 1 and 2, and `nth-child(2n) would span rows 2 and 3, and so on, but I am not sure whether CSS grid can do this. Do you perhaps know of a way to do this?

**UPDATED:** I guess this is a very rough CSS approximation of what I have in mind, using inline blocks: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JwXVox. I would welcome a better technique.

Answer (score 2):

Presumably, you know how to do your mobile version, and how to use `@media` to distinguish between different screen sizes.

I didn't fully understand what you meant by "span rows 1 and 2," but you don't have to use a grid layout. Good old-fashioned inline-blocks work fine here. Your rough approximation is rough only because your margin values are roughly estimated, not because the technique you're using is insufficient to do what you want.

Here's what I did to position the `.grid-element` elements (and it looks pretty even to me; perhaps it's close enough to what you want for you to fine tune it):

1. All elements: top margin of 0, left/right margins of 1%, bottom margin of 10px.
2. Second element (first element in right-hand column): top margin of 50px.
3. All odd-numbered elements except the first one: top margin of -50px.

You can experiment with the different margin values to see the effect that they have. But basically, once you have them set up side by side, you bump the second one down. That positions the second and first elements correctly, but all the subsequent elements get bumped down as well. So, we want to bump the even-numbered ones back up with a negative margin value. However, we don't want to bump the first one up, since it never got bumped down. So, we exclude it with the `nth-child(2n+3)` (i.e. every second element starting with three) selector. This is the equivalent of using `nth-child(odd):not(:first-child)`.

```js
function fillGrid() {
  const container = document.querySelector('.container');
  const times = [...new Array(10)];
  times.forEach(() => {
    const element = document.createElement('div');
    element.classList.add('grid-element');
    container.appendChild(element);
  });
}

fillGrid()
```

```css
.container {
  width: 60%;
  margin: auto;
  background: papayawhip;
  padding-bottom: 60px;
}

.grid-element {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 50px;
  background: green;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 48%;
  margin: 0 1% 10px;
}

.grid-element:nth-child(2) {
  margin-top: 60px;
}

.grid-element:nth-child(2n+3) {
  margin-top: -60px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
</div>
```

**EDIT: Using the CSS grid to get the same result**

After our conversation in the comments, I experimented with `position:grid` to see if I could figure out a way to do it. I had to add a line of javascript (or write a rather cumbersome bunch of CSS) to get it done, but it seems to work out.

I just set the row-height to 25%, and then added a line in your javascript to make each row two lines thick, and start it one line down from the previous element.

```js
function fillGrid() {
  const container = document.querySelector('.container');
  const times = [...new Array(10)];
  times.forEach((e, index) => {
    const element = document.createElement('div');
    element.classList.add('grid-element');
    //added the line below to size and position the elements
    element.setAttribute("style", "grid-row-start: " + (index + 1) + "; grid-row-end: " + (index + 3) + ";");
    element.textContent = index + 1; //also put a number in each box
    container.appendChild(element);
  });
}

fillGrid()
```

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 5px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-auto-rows: 25px;
  width: 60%;
  margin: auto;
  background: papayawhip;
}

.grid-element {
  background: green;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. As for what I meant by "span rows 1 and 2" and so on, here‘s an example I had in mind: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/Auto-placement_in_CSS_Grid_Layout#Items_with_placement_properties. Notice how block number two is positioned there in the grid at about half the height of block number five. Now, if there were a way to tell CSS grid to repeat this pattern, I think it would give a more robust solution to my problem. My hope was that there is such a way, and I simply am not aware of it. Meanwhile, I will try to go with your suggestion.

Comment: @azangru I see. Thanks for clarifying. I do notice that. Maybe there's a better way to use grids to do it. However, the inline-block solution is brittle only in the sense that you can't easily change the number of columns that you're working with. If you don't need to do that, it's hard to see exactly why the flexibility that grids offer is more robust. Can you elaborate a bit on why you think that the staggered inline-block solution is insufficiently robust? I'm asking out of interest and curiosity, not because I have already formed an opinion.

Comment: @azangru I put in a grid version. I used a line of JS to avoid some repetitive CSS, couldn't figure out how to do what I wanted without specifying each element individually. However, if you really wanted a CSS-only solution, you could add a class or id to each element (as I originally did) and then specify the `grid-row-start` and `grid-row-end` elements individually. Not very scalable, but if you don't need to scale and don't want to use JS to specify them, you can do that.

Comment: I realized that I forgot to mention a crucial detail about the layout: the elements to be distributed among the two columns can have unequal height. This makes solutions based on assumption of the element’s height (otherwise perfectly fine) unsuitable for this case. I opened a new question for this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53898032/distribute-elements-of-unequal-height-in-two-columns, hopefully it will not be closed down as a duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with the *Flexbox*, `calc()` *function*, `:nth-child()` *selectors*, `:not()` *pseudo-class* and of course `@media` *queries*:

```css
.flex {
  display: flex; /* displays flex-items (children) inline */
  flex-wrap: wrap; /* enables their wrapping */
}

.flex > div {
  flex-basis: calc(50% - 10px); /* initial width set to 50% of the parent's - left & right margins */
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0 5px; /* preferably top & bottom margins set to zero to keep calculations simple */
  border: 1px solid;
  box-sizing: border-box; /* because of the borders, also recommended in general */
}

.flex > div:nth-child(2){
  margin-top: 55px; /* half of divs height + half of the desired gap between them; modification affects all but the first div */
}

.flex > div:nth-child(odd):not(:first-child){
  margin-top: -45px; /* - half of divs height + half of the desired gap between them, so in this case the gap is 10px (2 x 5px); modification affects all but the first odd div (if ofc. modification is "")  */
}

.flex > div:nth-child(even):not(:nth-child(2)){
  margin-top: 10px; /* gap size; modification affects all but the first three divs */
}

@media (max-width: 600px){
  .flex {flex-direction: column} /* stacks flex-items vertically */
  .flex > div {flex-basis: auto} /* initial width set to default or 100% */
  .flex > div:not(:first-child) {margin-top: 10px !important}
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
  <div>7</div>
  <div>8</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This sort of works. But what the OP wants is to have, for example, is for the top of box 3 to be in the middle of box 2 rather than at the bottom of it. And so on. So, the margin value has to be added to box 2 and then subtracted from all the odd boxes except the first one. That said, I've played around with grid as well, and posted an edit to my answer, and I'm not sure I can see where flex or grid improves on inline-block in this case. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Ok updated. Well the biggest advantage imho is the amount of applied CSS, then ease of its modification, ofc. you need to know a "thing or two" about the Grid, being pretty complex and broad, it takes some time for beginners to really get the hang of it, and also staying up to date is never bad. Side note: The given "inline-block" solution is not so accurate as the latter one ('middle' deviations), but overall I like your dynamic approach and solution so +1 from my side.

Comment: Oops. Of course you're right; I failed to take the 10px margin into account. I fixed it. Now, I didn't see any way with grid to make every box two rows wide without specifying each one individually, which results in a lot of ponderous CSS, and I didn't want to resort to using margins, which seems to defeat the purpose of changing to grid. So I just used JS to do the ponderous CSS. If you know of a way to use CSS to say that each element takes two rows, without individually specifying them, I'd be glad to know how.

Answer (score 1):

A `float` approach

```css
.container {
  width: 250px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.item {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-top: calc(100px/3);
}

.item:first-child {
  margin-top: 0;
}


@media (min-width: 400px) {
  .item:nth-child(even) {
    float: right;
    margin-top: calc(-100px/3);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```